# Qooxdoo AJAX help - events not working?

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, couchdb, qooxdoo

I'm trying to make an AJAX call to CouchDB with Qooxdoo, but as far as I can tell no events seem to be firing on my request object (ie. Nothing is appearing on the console and no alerts are coming up). Can anyone tell me what should be happening/what I'm doing wrong?

(This is all in the 'main' method of my class)

```
  var req = new qx.io.remote.Request('http://localhost:5984/japanese/words', 'GET', 'application/json').set({crossDomain:true,timeout:0});
  this.debug("Testing");
  req.addListener("created", function(e) {
    this.debug("Created");
    alert(e.getContent());
  }, this);
  req.addListener("sending", function(e) {
    this.debug("Configured");
    alert(e.getContent());
  }, this);
  ...
```

(This is just a sample - I've added a similar listener for all the events I can think of but nothing is coming up on the console)

My server is running Ubuntu 10.10 with Qooxdoo 1.3.

Edit:

Now trying to request "http://localhost/languages/test.php" (my app is at "http://localhost/languages/index.html") and still no alerts are appearing except for the test one I put outside of any event. My request is now: `new qx.io.remote.Request('http://localhost/languages/test.php', 'GET', 'application/json');` The PHP file is returning valid JSON when I access it in my browser. Surely this should work?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side (your samples do not show)… Do you actually call the <code>send()</code> method in your code?

Answer (score 3):

Cross-domain requests in qooxdoo use a script transport which doesn't fire events. Instead, your server needs to wrap the response data in a call to a static method. See the package documentation of qx.io.remote for details:

http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.io.remote

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that in the docs. I'll try some other method/s of connecting. Thanks for the help!